# Unable to give spaces between divs when used display:table-cell

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I want to align 3 divs, next to each other. so I used `display:table` to the parent div and `display:table-cell` to the inner 3 divs.

Width of first 2 div is known and width of 3rd div is unknown. So the use of `display:table-cell` works perfectly for me to adjust the width of 3rd div.

Now if I want to give spacing between 3 divs using `margin-left` or `margin-right`, then there is no effect. Please check code [here](http://jsbin.com/avozik/edit#javascript,html).

Let me know if we can do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: quick fix: transparent border.

Comment: possible duplicate of [space between divs - display table-cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346083/space-between-divs-display-table-cell)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
 #wrapper div {
      display: table-cell;
      height:100px;
      /* creates space */
      border:5px solid transparent;
      background-clip:padding-box;
  }
```

You might want to set a different box-modell to include the border in the width of the elements via:

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use border property to give space like

```
border:solid 10px transparent;
```

Comment: this won't help, since outline occupies no space.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#wrapper {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:Gray;
    border-spacing:10px;
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsbin.com/avozik/7/edit#preview)

Comment: Your solution works but I just want spacing between one and two & two and three. Like this - http://jsbin.com/avozik/9/edit#preview

Comment: I think it's not possible using `table-cell`.

Answer (score 0):

Table cells cannot have margins. You can tweak it a bit by using transparent borders and if that doesn't solve your problem then there's no other way.